# Android SDK eclipse installation not working properly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

When I install the android SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
my file at the time was like `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.zip`. When I ran it, the eclipse looked very different. The loading screen showed Juno instead of the android loading screen. The icon on the bottom task toolbar (windows 7) was a unknown program icon and not the eclipse icon. When it opened, it looks like this image below.

If I try to create a new android activity file, after I click finish, I expect the file to be created, but nothing happens. Also if I go to the xml layout file and go to the gui explorer, I get a bunch of errors saying some widgets didn't load. And then it doesn't show the preview.

Some things work like intellisense and being able to run app on phone.

Im not sure if this has to do with corrupted preferences, so I deleted the files in here
`Eclipse Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime`, but it didn't help.

Does anyone know whats wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening? I also got the same layout two days ago.

Comment: Even When I created my first android application project, it gave me some error, and I wasn't able to fix it..It was like, I created a new android project and suddenly I got an error.

Comment: I think the fix is to install the most recent version. I am trying with `adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702` and so far (im installing api's now) it looks to work...

Comment: I suggest to use Android Studio IntelliJ based, or IntelliJ IDEA standalone, is far better than Eclipse for Android and Java based technologies development.

Answer (score 0):

I also installed the same version adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624.zip last week. It worked fine for the most part. The different icon and splash screen for Eclipse is to be expected. There were some oddities, like the link to SDK manager still pointed to my previous ADT installation.